# How to manipulate a hash-ref with Perl?

Tags: perl

Take a look at this code.  After hours of trial and error.  I finally got a solution. But have no idea why it works, and to be quite honest, Perl is throwing me for a loop here.

```
use Data::Diff 'Diff';
use Data::Dumper;

my $out = Diff(\@comparr,\@grabarr);

my @uniq_a;

@temp = ();
my $x = @$out{uniq_a};
foreach my $y (@$x) {
    @temp = ();
    foreach my $z (@$y) {
        push(@temp, $z);
    }
    push(@uniq_a, [$temp[0], $temp[1], $temp[2], $temp[3]]);
}
```

Why is it that the only way I can access the elements of the $out array is to pass a hash key into a scalar which has been cast as an array using a for loop?  `my $x = @$out{uniq_a};` I'm totally confused.  I'd really appreciate anyone who can explain what's going on here so I'll know for the future.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `uniq_a` declared?

Comment: What's wrong with `$out->{uniq_a}`? `@$out{uniq_q}` looks like a really indirect method of accessing a member of a hash reference using hash slice notation.

Comment: If you're not using @temp outside of the outer foreach loop, why not change `foreach my $y (@{$x}){ @temp = ();` to `foreach my $y ( @{$x} ) { my @temp;`?  (Not related to problem, but can't imagine why not clean up the scoping.

Comment: Fixed: uniq_a declared. I realize it's dirty, I'm cleaning it up as we speak, this was just to get it running in the first place. Thanks @DavidO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Diff` function returns a hash reference. You are accessing the element of this hash that has key `uniq_a` by extracting a one-element slice of the hash, instead of the correct `$out->{uniq_a}`. Your code should look like this

```
my $out = Diff(\@comparr, \@grabarr);

my @uniq_a;
my $uniq_a = $out->{uniq_a};
for my $list (@$uniq_a) {
  my @temp = @$list;
  push @uniq_a, [ @temp[0..3] ];
}
```

Comment: Wow. That never even occurred to me. Thanks a ton. That is so much more simple.

Comment: or just `for my $list (@{ $out->{uniq_a} })`.  see http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 4):

`$out` is a hash reference, and you use the dereferencing operator `->{...}` to access members of the hash that it refers to, like

```
$out->{uniq_a}
```

What you have stumbled on is Perl's hash slice notation, where you use the `@` sigil in front of the name of a hash to conveniently extract a list of values from that hash. For example:

```
%foo = ( a => 123, b => 456, c => 789 );
$foo = { a => 123, b => 456, c => 789 };
print @foo{"b","c"};    # 456,789
print @$foo{"c","a"};   # 789,123
```

Using hash slice notation with a single element inside the braces, as you do, is not the typical usage and gives you the results you want by accident.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~gcampbell/Data-Diff-0.01/Diff.pm) for `Data::Diff` it states:

> The value returned is always a hash reference and the hash will have
>   one or more of the following hash keys: type, same, diff, diff_a,
>   diff_b, uniq_a and uniq_b

So `$out` is a reference and you have to access the values through the mentioned keys.

Comment: Because $out{uniq_a} is not how you access values in a reference. You need to dereference it first. Either use: $$out{uniq_a} or $out->{uniq_a}